# JavaFX ToolTip Removing Page Corner

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, tooltip

I'm trying to remove the page corner from a tool tip but I'm failing to get the CSS to stick.

My Code Looks like:

```
public class PinRender extends StackPane {

private Shape shape;
private Text textNode;
private String text;

public PinRender(Shape shape) {
    this.shape = shape;
    this.textNode = new Text();
    this.text = "";
    this.getChildren().add(shape);
    this.getChildren().add(textNode);
    this.getStylesheets().add(PinRender.class.getResource("ToolTipStyle.css").toExternalForm());

    Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("ToolTips are the best!");
    tooltip.getStyleClass().add("ttip");

    Tooltip.install(this, tooltip);
}

public void setColor(Color c) {
    shape.setFill(c);
}
}
```

And my CSS looks like:

```
.ttip{
     -fx-background-radius: 0 0 0 0;
     -fx-background-color:  linear-gradient(white,whitesmoke);
}

.page-corner {
    -fx-shape: " ";
}
```

But I am still getting the default ugly yellow with the folded page corner.

Am I trying to use my CSS incorrectly?

Comment: Its JavaFX it just uses CSS to generate the renders. Unless I'm incorrect, I don't think it needs any HTML.

Comment: i think this would help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118145/how-to-create-good-looking-tooltip-with-small-arrow-on-the-corner-in-javafx/19724408#19724408

Comment: @AnshulParashar Im not sure the tool tip gets the style properly using that method since i'm using Tooltip.install()

Comment: @merjr this is global css for tool tip....yeah you can also use Tooltip.install() method and for change its css you can use tooltip.setStyle()...from this you can change you style as your need.

Comment: @AnshulParashar im currently using set style for the color but i cant seem to figure out how to remove the page fold

Comment: @merjr i think its remove by skin property..but setskin() may be useful for it.javafx 8 have a many skins property. but i am not preety sure how its working in javafx 2. i have one more better solution for it....you can use scene builder 2.0 thats you can download from here...in scene builder 2.0 tooltip not have page fold corner and its new way to design. try this i think its help you 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.page-corner {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```